# How to extract middle letters in a string?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I use list comprehension to extract all the middle letters of all the strings in Q[1]:

```
Q = [ ["Elizabeth","Victoria","Elizabeth"],
      ["Eleanor","Blanche","Margaret","Isabella","Anne","Catherine","Marguerite","Mary","Anne"],
      ["Padmini","Chennamma","Sultana","Holkar"],
      ["Artemisia","Kratesipolis","Nikaia","Olympias"]
    ]
```

So far all I have is this:

```
L = [ x for x in Q[1] if len(x) % 2 != 0 ]
print(L)
```

But this only prints out all the strings with an odd number of characters, in which a middle letter can be found.

```
['Eleanor', 'Blanche', 'Catherine']
```

The output has to be:

```
['a','n','e']
```

Comment: no I just want all the middle letters of all the words in just Q[1]

Comment: which are ['Eleanor', 'Blanche', 'Catherine']

Comment: "just want all the middle letters of all the words in just Q[1] " -- then, why do you want only 3 letters when there are 9 words in Q[1]?

Comment: only 3 words in Q[1] have an odd number of letters, I'm not interested in the words with an even number of characters because they don't have a middle letter

Comment: In that case try: `[x[len(x) // 2] for x in Q[1] if len(x) % 2]`.  It uses`len(x) % 2` to detect odd length strings and `x[len(x) // 2]` for the middle letter.  This produces your desired output.

Comment: how come it's not `if len(x) % 2 == 0`?

Comment: `len(x) % 2 == 0` is True when `x` is even length i.e. has an even number of characters.  You want an odd number.  `len(x) % 2` is non-zero when `len(x)` is odd.  Being non-zero makes it True as a boolean value in the if condition.

Answer (score -2):

Using the following code

```py
L = [x[int(len(x) / 2)] for x in Q[1] if len(x) % 2]
print(L)
```

you will get `['a', 'n', 'e']`

---

```
if len(x) % 2
```

Will be true only when the result of `len(x) % 2` is different than zero, e.g. when the string has a odd number of characters.

```
x[int(len(x) / 2)]
```

This piece of the list comprehension will take the middle letter by calculating the length of the list and taking the index at the half way.